# sql Could not find stored procedure ''. with bit as a return type

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using SQL server management studio, i am trying to update something in my database the return type of that column is bit so its either 0 or 1: this is my sql statment:

```
public void Update(int ID)
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new sqlConnection etc....; 
    string query = "UPDATE Table SET ColumnName= ColumnName^ 1 WHERE ID=@ID";
    SqlCommand myComm = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
    myComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
    myConnection.Open();
    myComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

    myConnection.Close();
}
```

I am getting a error saying  "Could not find stored procedure", can someone help me what does this means: i have looked around the web but i just dont understand? 
Based on a ID i should be able to change the bit to 0 to 1 or 1 to 0.
Also is there any problem with my SQL statement? because i am also getting a error saying Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: `myComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` But you run a query and no procedure. Change the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
myComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

to

```
myComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

(or just remove it since `CommandType.Text` is the default)

You are not executing a stored procedure - you are executing direct SQL.

Comment: I tried this, it works but now i am getting a error saying: Incorrect syntax near '='. But syntax looks fine, I tried it out in database and it works fine. its complaining it near ColumnName= ColumnName

Answer (score 1):

I think you should to remove this line

`myComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

You are not calling a procedure.. Hence, you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
myComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

to

```
myComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

You run a query and not a *Stored Procedure*.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting CommandType.StoredProcedure whereas  you are actually executing a sql query. You should use CommandType.Text.

On other note, I will never use inline sql statements. It is a bad coding practice and leads to security and maintainability issues. I will advice you to move your code to a store procedure.